# Android activity navigation bug

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-orientation, android-savedstate

I'm having a weird bug that I'm not sure how to debug. I have have an activity set up to show movie trailers and reviews. Everything looks and works fine when the app is initially started unless I navigate away from the app to another app or youtube to watch the trailer. Then when I come back into my app the trailer names and reviews are all out of the original order and just messed up (some are duplicated). However when I click on the the trailer name (that is now incorrect) it takes me to the correct trailer! Also when I come back to the app if I try rotating the phone sideways it won't rotate. Rotation and everything else works perfectly fine before I navigate away from the app and come back. I'm so confused. I've tried different onSaveInstanceState etc. implementations but nothing is working. I don't even know what code snippet to post since I don't know where the error could possibly be occurring.

[image]

Comment: Your views are getting recycled and you aren't handing this properly. Show the code from `getView()` in the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup as David Wasser wrote above the issue was with my adapter and nothing to do with onSaveInstanceState. I was assigning the textview in the incorrect method of the adapter (I was assigning it where I defined my viewholder and not on the onBind method) so it wasn't being handled properly.